# What does "using X = int(&)()" do?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been seen following type of code when i browsing Quora.

```
#include <iostream>
int f() 
{ 
   return 1; 
}

int main()
{
    int (&var1)() = f;
    using X = int(&)();
    int i = reinterpret_cast<X>(var1)();
    std::cout << " i = " << i << '\n';
}
```

So, What does `using X = int(&)()` do?

Answer (score 2):

The statement is making `X` be an alias to the type on the right hand side of the equal sign.

That alias is then being used in the next statement.

See [this reference page on the using keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cpp/aliases-and-typedefs-cpp).